# How to fix this WCAG error "This form control has a blank label or title."

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wcag

I am running Sortsite for the ADA compliance on a website I'm working on and I get this message:

This form control has a blank label or title. 
Add descriptive text to the form control's label.

I've tried adding the label element with some information but hide it because we don't want it shown.

```
<label style="display: none;" for="slide1">First slide</label>
<input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" title="First set of slides" />
```

Comment: A label that is `display: none` isn't there, so it doesn't help people access the form!

Comment: Checkbox, label text “First slide” - is this one of those sliders made with an “avoid JavaScript at all cost” approach? Those usually have _terrible_ usability in general. Stuff like this is nice as “proof of concept” - but they are _not_ a good solution for actual use in practice. If you want _proper_ accessibility, then don’t use these techniques to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Screen readers and other accessibility devices don't use the DOM, but build and [accessibility tree](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-builtin/the-accessibility-tree) based on it. Invisible items don't go there.

If you don't want your label to be visible, use an [aria-label](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA14.html):

```
<div class="_po-r">
  <div class="_bl-zi-0a _w-01 _bl-bg-0l " id="slides">
    <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" class="set" title="First set of slides" aria-label="First slide" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the label to be visible on screen, place it off-screen by using a .visually-hidden, .sr_only CSS class with code such as the following.
**NEVER use display:none**., as it **hides the label for everybody including screen reader users**.

```
.visually-hidden {
position: absolute;
left: -2px;
top: auto;
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Great are the chances that if you are using a framework like bootstrap, they already propose such a class.

If you can do so, it's better to always have a label, even if it is off-screen, rather than using aria-label.
The first gold rule of ARIA is that **it should only be used when it is really necessary**. Here you can avoid it very easily.